# Slow Excel Table Update/Filtering When Using Lookup

Tags: performance, updates, lookup, excel-tables

I am currently experiencing a recurring/general problem when using Excel tables.  When a table is being "looked up" from elsewhere in the workbook, the table is slow to update/refresh. When entering a value to a cell within the table, I am unable to move to another cell for 6 seconds.

The number of rows doesn't seem to make a difference, nor does the type of lookup e.g. Vlookup,Xlookup,Index/Match,Filter. I've deleted unused rows/columns around the table.  There is no conditional formatting.

Removing the lookups to the table, from elsewhere in the workbook seems to resolve the issue - the update is instant, but doing this makes the workbook redundant.  Alternatively leaving the lookups in place and converting the table to a range also resolves the issue, but this makes the benefits of using tables redundant.